# OTRS - ACL is blocking state change in ViewNote

Tags: acl, otrs

I have two ACLs defined to filter allowed state-transitions. Something like

1.ACL: state_A

```
      - Match settings:
           - Properties
                - Ticket
                     - State: state_A
       - Possible:
            - Ticket
                 - State: state_B
```

2.ACL: state_B

```
      - Match settings:
           - Properties
                - Ticket
                     - State: state_B
       - Possible:
            - Ticket
                 - State: state_A
```

Where state_A is of a custom type, and state_B is of type closed. I want to allow really simple state transition when I click on "Edit Note".

If the ACLs are disabled, I can in the Note easily change from one state to another. However, if the first ACL is enabled, which should only allow transition from A to B (and should not influence transitions from B to A) I cannot move from B to A(!).

I tried to search if I am not "blocking" myself in the Generic agent (probably automatically switching from A back to B), but no. To me it does not make any sense. Can it have something to do that I want to change a closed ticket state to some custom ticket state? If that's so, why does it work if I disable the ACLs?

Has anyone had a samilar experience? Any hints what might have gone wrong are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) for me it's not clear what your use case is and what you try to cover.

2) Normally the ACLs as you describe will only allow to set the ticket state to state_B if the current selected ticket state in UI is state_A. And if you select state_B it only allows to to set state_A anymore. -> So from me both ACLs at same time makes no sense (refer to 1).

3) There is no restriction to regarding ACLs and custom states. It should work as well.